# Os Nomes Usados Para Avôs de Avôs

Tags: expressões, vocabulário

Eu estava lendo e encontrei a palavra "trisavô" e acertei o sentido de "pai do bisavô". Então buscei as palavras para os outros "avôs" e achei que tem mais que um jeito de falar.

O que significa "tataravô", é "pai do bisavô" ou "avô do bisavô"?
Também, qual se usa mais, os numeros ordinais (quinto avô, sexto avô), os prefixos (pentavô, hexavô), o as "tataras" (tataravô, tatara-tataravô, tatara-tatara-tataravô)?

Esta órdem é correta?

1. avô
2. bisavô
3. trisavô (tataravô?)
4. tetravô (quarto avô?) (tatara-tataravô?)
5. quintavô (quinto avô?) (tatara-tatara-tataravô?)
6. hexavô (sexto avô?) (tatara-tatara-tatara-tataravô?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, essa ordem é a correta.

Mas *[tataravô](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/tatarav%C3%B4)* é o mesmo que *[tetravô](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/tetrav%C3%B4)*.

A partir do tetravô/tataravô não existem palavras dicionarizadas. Mas isto não te impede de as inventar. Se as as outras pessoas entenderem...

O que te impede de as inventar, é que já alguém as inventou! Se fores ao Google Books encontras ***pentavô*** em 66 publicações, começando com [esta de 1937](https://books.google.pt/books?id=c04MAQAAIAAJ&q=pentav%C3%B4&dq=pentav%C3%B4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDxrXYmKfSAhVDBBoKHQFMDDs4MhDoAQhxMA4), pela pena do escritor brasileiro [Agrippino Grieco (Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agripino_Grieco).

*Pentavô* usa o antepositivo *penta* de origem grega, tal como *tetravô* usa *tetra*, também de origem grega. Mas se preferires origem latina, tal como *bi* de *bisavô*, o antepositivo que vem no Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) é *quinque* ou *quinqui*, como em *quinquénio*. Portanto não seria *quintavô*, mas talvez *quinqueavô?* Ou ***quincavô***: [*quincálogo* (Priberam)](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/quinc%C3%A1logo) é um conjunto de cinco mandamentos da Igreja Católica. Também já *quincavô* foi inventado: encontras uma meia dúzia de ocorrências na net.

Se quiseres mais, [este livro](https://books.google.pt/books?id=bTVGBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA70&dq=pentav%C3%B4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgs5W5nafSAhVDVRoKHTaDCfMQ6AEIdjAM#v=onepage&q=pentav%C3%B4&f=false), mantendo-se fiel aos antepositivos de origem grega, sugere *hexavô, heptavô* e *octavô*.

*Tatara-tataravô* existe, mas é apenas um regionalismo brasileiro para indicar um ancestral bastante distante. A palavra não é dicionarizada, costuma não ser grafada com hífen, e pode apresentar variações infinitamente longas, como *tataratataratataratataravô*, a fim de representar as hipérboles tradicionalmente utilizadas na linguagem informal brasileira:

> Então a inteligência por trás do DNA é uma obra do acaso ? Legal, vou despejar um caminhão de tijolos e demais agregados, pra ver se cria uma casa…
>   O DNA é tão complexo e inteligente, que sinceramente o seu tatarataratarataravô, Sr. Vácuo não poderia criar. (mesmo com bilhões de anos)
>   <sub>Fonte: [Coluna de Salvador Nogueira na versão digital do jornal Folha de São Paulo](http://mensageirosideral.blogfolha.uol.com.br/2014/04/09/universo-veio-do-nada-dizem-fisicos/comment-page-1/)</sub>

Comment: Mas *tetra* é grego; não devia ser *pentavô?*

Comment: Pumba! Cá está o @Jacinto, cada tiro cada melro! Não queres ajeitar a resposta? Torna-a *Community Wiki*.

Comment: Eh, pá! é preciso isso. Para mim, isto dos *quintavô* ou *pentavô*, é uma brincadeira. Quem é que vai usar essas palavras?

Comment: Tive a pôr umas coisas. Não sei o que fazer com o *tatara-tataravô*, mas quando muito seria o tetravô do tetravô, não? O octavô, creio. A versão latina de *hexavô* seria, creio, *sexavô*.

Comment: Adicionei a explicação do tatara-tataravô, com o exemplo mais _formal_ que consegui encontrar.

Comment: @Jacinto, minha família faz muita genealogia (história de família), então de vez em quando falamos dos antepassados distantes.
Em inglês, usamos grandfather (avô), great-grandfather (bisavô), great-great-grandfather (trisavô), etc. Cada geração adicione um "great". Pode dizer "Fifth great-grandfather" (avô de cinco 'greats', ou sexto avô).
Parece que "tatara-tataravô" é parecido com "many 'greats' grandfather" (avô de muitos 'greats'), que significa um antepassado muito distante.

Answer (score 5):

Da minha vivência no Rio de Janeiro eu conheço os seguintes termos: pai/mãe, avô/avó, bisavô/bisavó, trisavô/trisavó, tataravô/tataravó. Já tetravô/tetravó, que parecem ser os termos corretos, eu só ouvi recentemente. O site [**"gramática e questões vernáculas"**](http://gramaticaequestoesvernaculas.blogspot.com.br/2014/07/bisavo-trisavo-tetravo-tataravo-dicas.html) usa a seguinte terminologia.

> **Bisavô é o pai do avô** (bi, de dois); **trisavô, o pai do bisavô** (tri, de três); **tetravô, o pai do trisavô** (tetra, de quatro). Para o tetravô existe a variante popular **tataravô** (e apenas para o tetravô). 
>   Assim, **bisavó é a mãe da avó**; **trisavó, a mãe da bisavó**; **tetravó ou tataravó, a mãe da trisavó.**
>   Os netos também têm seus prefixos: **bisneto**, o
>   filho do neto; **trineto**, o filho do bisneto; **tetraneto ou tataraneto**, o filho do trineto.

Na verdade, eu costumo voltar no tempo até bisavô/bisavó e, a partir daí digo "o avô do meu avô", etc. Nunca precisei voltar mais do que três gerações no tempo, mesmo porque não cheguei a conhecer meus trisavós. E, o que ouço com mais frequência é mesmo: o pai do meu bisavô, o avô do avô do meu tataravô, coisas desse tipo. Nunca ouvi ninguém usando uma palavra específica para mais do que quatro gerações, exceto em uma única ocasião quando um jornalista quis se referir a um descendente de George III da Inglaterra, mas não me recordo bem qual o termo utilizado para o seu descendente de sexta geração.